# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path

Tags: json, .net, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to parse a string to JSON, and it works if I parse it to `JObject`, but if I try to parse to my own custom type, I'm getting an error when it tries to parse the `Properties` property

> error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character
> encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'Properties', line 1,
> position 212.'

```
var str2 = "{\"Timestamp\":\"2024-02-15T12:55:03.9797576+02:00\",\"Level\":\"Information\",\"MessageTemplate\":\"User profile is available. Using '{FullName}' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.\",\"Properties\":{\"FullName\":\"C:\\\\Users\\\\Buga\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\ASP.NET\\\\DataProtection-Keys\",\"EventId\":{\"Id\":63,\"Name\":\"UsingProfileAsKeyRepositoryWithDPAPI\"},\"SourceContext\":\"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager\"}}";

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(str2); // this works
var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogItem>(str2);  // error here

 public class LogItem
 {
     public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }

     public string Level { get; set; }

     public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }

     public string Properties { get; set; }

     public string SourceContext { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `string Properties`, so it is expecting something like:

```json
"Properties": "foo"
```

but the JSON has an object:

```json
"Properties":{"FullName": ... }
```

So, one of:

- change the `Properties` type to be a suitable object
- use JSON that has a *string* properties

The model must match the data.

Something like:

```cs
public class LogItem
{
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }

    public string Level { get; set; }

    public string MessageTemplate { get; set; }

    public LogItemProperties Properties { get; set; }
    public string SourceContext { get; set; }
}

public class LogItemProperties
{
    public LogEventId EventId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
public class LogEventId
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

As an aside: prefer "raw strings" for handling JSON literals (and XML literals, etc):

```cs
var str2 = """{"Timestamp":"2024-02-15T12:55:03.9797576+02:00","Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"User profile is available. Using '{FullName}' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.","Properties":{"FullName":"C:\\Users\\Buga\\AppData\\Local\\ASP.NET\\DataProtection-Keys","EventId":{"Id":63,"Name":"UsingProfileAsKeyRepositoryWithDPAPI"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager"}}""";
```

or formatted, if you prefer (although this changes the `string` value:

```cs
var str2 = """
{
    "Timestamp":"2024-02-15T12:55:03.9797576+02:00",
    "Level":"Information",
    "MessageTemplate":"User profile is available. Using '{FullName}' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.",
    "Properties":{
        "FullName":"C:\\Users\\Buga\\AppData\\Local\\ASP.NET\\DataProtection-Keys",
        "EventId":{
            "Id":63,
            "Name":"UsingProfileAsKeyRepositoryWithDPAPI"
        },
        "SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager"
    }
}
""";
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I tell it somehow, to read Properties as a string ?

Comment: changing Properties to `object` fixed it ( Properties won't be the same type all the time); and I can serialize it back if I need it as a string. Thank You.

Comment: @buga note the model suggestion above - in particular, note that your `SourceContext` looks to be at the wrong location; I'll also add a second edit in a moment, showing a better way to treat JSON as literals in C#

Comment: done; I was wrong about the `SourceContext`, though - mea culpa

Comment: I've used an online js beautifier, and ineed, SourceContext is inside Properties, I'm trying to read Serilog JSON logs, and I wrote the Type by looking at the log's text.

Comment: one last thing, was having issue with the "Properties" not being desererialized as object with properties, but as some sort of jtoken array, switched to `System.Text.Json` instead of Newtonsoft and it all works now.